# how can edpm or a rubber like material be attached to pvc board?

Tags: materials

Considering using 4 pvc boards for dug well cover.  Need a sealing layer to keep water out.  A mastic might work too.

Comment: I'd be **very** leery of using PVC boards (without a sturdy frame of some sort) to cover a 4 foot well (size from your prior question) as they would be likely to collapse if a person or large animal (prior question mentioned woods location) stood on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use EPDM and Pvc.  EPDM is notoriously hard to bond and what few adhesives you can use aren't going to be made for use around potable water.  I'd worry about chemicals that leech out of the adhesive contaminating the well.

I would stick to materials and adhesives that are known to be safe around potable water.  PVC is safe for pipes but I don't know if PVc deck boards are.  If you want to use PVC boards, you could use stainless sheet metal over them as a waterproof membrane.  Stainless is not cheap but does hold up.

Comment: Well is former gravity well on property.  Hasn't been used in 20 years.  Old cover is wood frame with asphalt shingles.  Goal is to never have to deal with this cover again.  Water might be potable,  I only used it in the past for washing, showering and toilet.